# Disable SqsListener on specific instances

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, sqslistener

I have a spring boot application where i am using SQS for some async tasks.
I want to configure 2 types of instances in this application:

1. Server instance: responsible for pushing message to SQS queue.
2. Worker instance: responsible for listening messages from SQS queue.

For listening messages I am using `@SqsListener` annotation like this:

```
    @SqsListener("queue_name")
    public void loadMessagesFromQueue(Object message) {
        log.info("inside loadMessagesFromQueue");
        log.info("Queue Messages: " + message);
    }
```

The ask here is that i want to disable this `SqsListener` on the server instance and just want it to run on the worker instance. How do I achieve this? I have tried searching if there is a way to disable it using some config variable but didn't find anything

Comment: And your server and worker instances are running the same jar even though they do very different things!?

Comment: Yes, they are running the same jar. Only the yaml/properties file could be different for server and worker instances

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way to do it. I have created 2 separate YAML files for server and worker instances and configured a variable `cloud.aws.sqs.autoStart` in both the YAML files. I have kept the value of autoStart as True on the worker instance and as False on the server instance.

While creating the `SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory` I am using this variable like this:

```
    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSqs);
        factory.setAutoStartup(autoStart);
        factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(5);


        return factory;
    }
```